# How to analyze which part of code creates a thread?

Tags: c++, debugging, pthreads, analysis

i have to analyze a very big C++ project in terms of thread creation. It's not my project and the threads were not labeled. Number and selection of threads vary depending on the input.

What is an efficient way to find out, which part of code creates a specific thread during runtime?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you let us know what OS and compiler/IDE you are using?
Different operating systems have different tool-sets available...

For example, in GNU/Linux with GDB, adding a breakpoint to pthread_create and family could be a good start....   this would be usless to you on Win32 tho...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ...

Linux & GCC

The project is too big. Okay, it's possible to write a script that will do it for me, but then i have to debug. What i want is the possibility to see it during runtime, with a tracer etc.

Comment: Do you want to debug what is happening in the threads or do you want to see where the threads are created and how? Thread creation is a matter of searching for the appropriate calls. Debugging on the other hand is a bit more tricky. I know of two commercial tools that do this very well. One is totalview and the other is Allinea ddt

Comment: @Ashkan Thanks, didn't know about TotalView and Allinea.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you mention the idea of a `tracer'.  With that in mind you might be able to make use of [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

Consider the following piece of code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

typedef int (*real_pthread_create_t)(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                                     void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);

static real_pthread_create_t real_pthread_create = NULL;
static unsigned thread_count = 0;

extern "C"
int
pthread_create (pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg)
{

  /*
   * If real_pthread_create hasn't been fixed up yet then do it now.
   */
  if (!real_pthread_create)
    real_pthread_create = (real_pthread_create_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");

  /*
   * Increment the thread count.
   */
  ++thread_count;

  /*
   * Dump some stats and the call stack to cerr.
   */
  std::cerr << "\ncreated thread #" << thread_count
            << "\nStack trace...\n"
            << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();

  /*
   * Delegate to the real pthread_create and simply forward its return value.
   */
  return real_pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}
```

Compile the above code into a shared object with something like...

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o pthread_catcher.so pthread_catcher.cpp
```

and then use it as...

```
LD_PRELOAD=pthread_catcher.so ./path-to-main-application
```

A quick test on some home grown code shows output such as...

```
created thread #7
Stack trace...
 0# pthread_create in build/objs/how-to-analyze-which-part-of-code-creates-a-thread.so
 1# 0x00007F311A7EF91C in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 2# 0x00007F311A7EFD75 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 3# 0x00007F311A7E7E22 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 4# 0x00007F311AA08FF4 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 5# 0x00007F311AA09379 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 6# 0x00007F311AA9BC73 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 7# nouveau_drm_screen_create in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 8# 0x00007F311A52FBC6 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
 9# 0x00007F311AA00DB8 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
10# 0x00007F311A8D6042 in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
11# 0x00007F311A8D144E in /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so
12# 0x00007F311B6688FE in /usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0
13# 0x00007F311B640BA3 in /usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0
14# 0x00007F311B63C284 in /usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0
15# 0x00007F311B63CC9D in /usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0
16# 0x00007F3121BEBA50 in /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
17# QXcbWindow::create() in /usr/lib64/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
18# QXcbIntegration::createPlatformWindow(QWindow*) const in /usr/lib64/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
19# QWindowPrivate::create(bool, unsigned long long) in /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5
20# QWidgetPrivate::create_sys(unsigned long long, bool, bool) in /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5
21# QWidget::create(unsigned long long, bool, bool) in /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5
22# QWidget::setVisible(bool) in /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5
23# main in ./build/applications/vnet/test00005
24# __libc_start_main in /lib64/libc.so.6
25# _start in ./build/applications/vnet/test00005
```

Comment: That's an awesome approach, very cool ... i will try it and make a report!

Comment: It's working very well, but i have problems with the stacktrace output format. So i can not see where the pthread_create call is coming from. I'm working on it.